# How to trigger my javascript pop up form with WordPress navigation link?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I've created a javascript pop up contact form, how do I trigger this after clicking a WordPress navigation item?

I have already tried the following code which works fine. However, after 1 second it loads the page which I've set the nav item to in WordPress.

```
document.getElementById('menu-item-177').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.bg-modal').style.display = "flex";
  $('body').css('overflow','hidden')
});
```

I tried deleting the page, but obviously the nav link disappears. I also tried removing the menu item in the Menu settings of WordPress, same outcome.

I somehow need to block the page loading when the nav link is clicked. Is there a way round this?

Comment: You need to stop navigation and open up the popup instead, is that correct?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier yes, that's right

Comment: And what kind of element is the `#menu-item-177` element?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier This is the navigation class WordPress generated.

Comment: I know that, it's the ID of an element, but what element? `<li>`? `<a>`?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier It's a <li>, but it has a child element of <a>. see this screenshot https://ibb.co/M82sn67

Comment: Awesome, well done. I've updated my answer below to include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are selecting the `<a href="..` anchor element and listen for the click on that. I see that you have jQuery loaded in, so it might be good to just use that, or don't use it at all.

In your click event listener you listen for a click to happen. Whenever this click happens the function in the listener will be called. This function exposes some information about the event in the `Event` object. You'll see this in other pieces of code named `e`, `evt`, `event` or something else to refer to this `Event` object.

The `Event` object has a method called [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) which stops the browser from executing any kind of behavior that is linked to that element. Like navigating with an `<a>` tag. See why it is important to know what element you are clicking on? By adding that you can add your own behavior. See the example below.

```
$('#menu-item-177 > a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevents default navigation behavior.
  $('.bg-modal').css('display', 'flex');
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I have been looking for an answer for about a week. Your first answer actually worked, but I also tried your updated answer and they both worked. Have a great day!